# Changing src of embedded video works in FF but not in IE or Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, video, cross-browser, embed

I'm wanting to change the source of the embedded video when the user clicks on one of the elements in my list of videos. It works fine in FF but in both IE and Chrome, nothing happens. Can anyone tell me how I can get this functionality to work properly across all browsers? 
Heres my JavaScript:

```
function updateSource(id)
{ 
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    video.src=document.getElementById(id).getAttribute('data-value');
}
```

And Here is my HTML:

```
<embed id="video" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/h5NeJaWR5WA?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0&showinfo=0"
            type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="480" height="360"
            allowscriptaccess="never" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>


<li id="one" class="videoLink" style="margin-top: -1em;" onclick="updateSource(this.id)"
 data-value="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/h5NeJaWR5WA?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0&showinfo=0">
      <img class="youtubeThumb" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/h5NeJaWR5WA/default.jpg" />
      <p class="videoTitle">Video Number One!</p>
</li>
<li id="two" class="videoLink" onclick="updateSource(this.id)"
 data-value="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/r19okL-IW6Q?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0&showinfo=0">
      <img class="youtubeThumb" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/r19okL-IW6Q/default.jpg" />
      <p class="videoTitle">Video Number Two!</p>
</li>
```

Comment: Where's the video element?? You provided incomplete HTML.

Comment: I noticed it right after I posted. It's updated now.

Comment: Also, you should never start an id with a number. This is clearly stated in the W3C spec (and known to cause problems). http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name. Also, make sure ids are not duplicated. -- just to be clear, in all fairness, numbers for IDs generally don't cause problems... unless you start writing script to access the DOM (which is what's happening here).

Comment: You still don't have a `video` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/tuDXg/4/

I don't believe the `embed` element supports updating the `src` attribute. You should wrap it in a div and change the div's `innerHTML` to be a new `embed` element with the updated src.

Comment: Thank you! This works great! I did not think of replacing the entire `embed` element.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it does look like the number (id value) is the problem. It thinks you're passing an integer (not a string) as an index (not an id value).

Comment: I changed the ids to be 'one' and 'two' and I still have the same problem. I updated my code.

Comment: It turns out the numbers as the id are okay. See my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tuDXg/4/).